# Trying to implement waves of enemies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a waves of enemies, where you need to create a new wave when the current wave has been destroyed.

**Wave Code**

```
[SerializeField] List<WaveConfig> waveConfigs;
[SerializeField] int startingWave = 0;

WaveConfig waveConfig;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemyInWawe());
}

IEnumerator SpawnAllEnemyInWawe()
{
    for(int waweIndex = startingWave; waweIndex < waveConfigs.Count; waweIndex++)
    {
        var currentWave = waveConfigs[waweIndex];
    
        yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemyInWawe(currentWave));
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnAllEnemyInWawe(WaveConfig waveConfig)
{
    for(int enemyCount = 0; enemyCount<waveConfig.GetEnemyNumberOfParh(); enemyCount++)
    {
        GameObject newEnemy = Instantiate(waveConfig.GetEnemyPrefabs(), 
        waveConfig.GetEnemyWaiponts()[0].transform.position,
        Quaternion.identity);
        newEnemy.GetComponent<EnemyPath>().SetWaveConfig(waveConfig);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveConfig.GetTimeMegduSpawnomEnemy());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: waweIndex instead of waveIndex won't solve your issue just wanted to point that out

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your point correctly.

1. this code not help you to wait previous wave was eliminate, it work flow is spawn next wave instantly after previous wave spawn completed.

```
IEnumerator SpawnAllEnemyInWawe()
{
    for(int waweIndex = startingWave; waweIndex < waveConfigs.Count; waweIndex++)
    {
        var currentWave = waveConfigs[waweIndex];
    
        yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemyInWawe(currentWave));
    }
}
```

2. IF you need to wait until current wave eliminate.
   When wave begin, you should track all enemies in the wave (eg. amount, alive data, or something) and check it for start next wave.

**Psudo :**

```
void Update(){
   if(enemyInWave == 0){ // Or Condition is fullfill to start next wave
      NextWave();
   }else {
      // Do Nothing
   }
}

void NextWave(){
   var waveConfig = WaveConfig[currentWaveIndex]
   enemyInWave = waveConfig.monsters.Amount
   SpanwEnemy(waveConfig.monsters)
}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `static` HashSet/List where you store all instances of created enemies. The enemies simply add and remove themselves to/from the HastSet during their lifetime.

Then you can simply wait until no enemies are left before going into the next wave.

Something like

```
public class YourWaveClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] List<WaveConfig> waveConfigs;
    [SerializeField] int startingWave = 0;

    private static HastSet<Enemy> currentlyAliveEnemies = new HashSet<Enemy>();

    public static void Add(Enemy enemy)
    {
        if(!currentlyAliveEnemies.Contains(enemy)) currentlyAliveEnemies.Add(enemy);
    }

    public static void Remove(Enemy enemy)
    {
        if(currentlyAliveEnemies.Contains(enemy)) currentlyAliveEnemies.Remove(enemy);
    }
    
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemyInWawe());
    }
    
    IEnumerator SpawnAllEnemyInWawe()
    {
        for(int waweIndex = startingWave; waweIndex < waveConfigs.Count; waweIndex++)
        {
            var currentWave = waveConfigs[waweIndex];
        
            yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemyInWawe(currentWave));
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerator SpawnAllEnemyInWawe(WaveConfig waveConfig)
    {
        for(int enemyCount = 0; enemyCount<waveConfig.GetEnemyNumberOfParh(); enemyCount++)
        {
            // NOTE: It would be better/saver if you make your prefab directly of type Enemy then
            var newEnemy = Instantiate(waveConfig.GetEnemyPrefabs(), waveConfig.GetEnemyWaiponts()[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            newEnemy.GetComponent<EnemyPath>().SetWaveConfig(waveConfig);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveConfig.GetTimeMegduSpawnomEnemy());
        }

        // Now wait until the HashSet is empty => all enemies are dead
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => currentlyAliveEnemies.Count == 0);
    }
}
```

So what you need to have on your enemy prefabs would be a component like

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This is automatically called during Instantiate
    private void Awake()
    {
        YourWaveClass.Add(this);
    }

    // this is called automatically when your object gets destroyed/dies
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        YourWaveClass.Remove(this);
    }
}
```